# redimension multidimensional arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Take a look at the following code.  What my problem is is that I can't figure out how to redimension the n integer and the b integer.  What I'm doing is the array sent1 is already working and it is populated with about 4 sentences.  I need to go through each sentence and work on it but I'm having trouble.

```
dim sent1() 
dim sent2()

dim n as integer, b as integer, x as integer
dim temp_sent as string
b = 0
For n = 1 to ubound(sent1)

temp_sent = sent1(n)
    for x = 1 to len(temp_sent1)
    code
    if a then
        b = b + 1
        '**THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE THAT IS NOT WORKING**
        redim preserve sent2(1 to ubound(sent1), b)
        sent2(n,b) = [code]
    next
next
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a better site for specific coding questions.

Comment: gotta love vba array support.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. When you `Dim` an array without specifying the lower bound it will by default be `0` based (unless you have specified `Option Base 1`).  When explicitly specified, lower bound can be *any* number, not just `0` or `1`
2. For a multi dimensioned array, `Redim Preserve` can only change the *last* dimension, and then only the upper bound.

In general, I find it better to *always* specify Lower and Upper bounds, eg

```
Redim MyArray(1 to 10, 0 to 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you want to / must use arrays?

If not, I'd suggest using collections instead. You can also have nested collections, e.g.

```
Dim dimension1 As New Collection
Dim dimension2 AS New Collection

dimension1.Add dimension2
```

etc.

That way, you won't have to worry about increasing dimensions manually at all. If you need to convert it back to a 2D Array, you can do sth like this in the end

```
Dim item AS Variant
Dim subCollection AS Collection

Dim nRows AS Integer
Dim nCols AS integer

' assuming "col" is your jagged collection

nRows = col.Count
For Each item in col
  If TypeOf item is Collection
    Set subCollection = item
    If subCollection.Count > nCols Then
      nCols = subCollection.Count
    End If
  Next item
Next item

Dim result(nRows, NCols) As Variant

' Now loop through the collections again and fill the result array
```

Comment: I've never heard of collections before.  I'll discuss them with my tutor.  I've found a solution to this problem.  I don't know if this website closes questions but for my purposes I'm done with this.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you have is that you cannot change the rank (dimensions) of an array with a `redim` statement.

`dim sent()` creates a 1-rank array, `redim sent2(x, y)` assumes a 2-rank array. Try `dim sent(,)`.

Also, it will improve performance (and code robustness) if you use

```
dim sent1() as string
dim sent2(,) as string
```

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone has this problem here is how I solved it:

```
<code>
Function find_sentences_complex(instring As String) As Variant

Dim xorr As String: xorr = ChrW(&H22BB)
Dim triple_bar As String: triple_bar = ChrW(&H2261)
Dim idisj As String: idisj = ChrW(&H2228)
Dim cond As String: cond = ChrW(&H2192)
 Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer, b As Integer
Dim total As Integer, paren_closure As Integer, marker As Boolean
 Dim n As Integer

Dim sent1() As Variant, sent3() As Variant

'Dim final1d As Integer, final2d As Integer
Dim b_arr() As Integer
Dim b_max As Integer




   Dim temp_string As String

        For x = InStr(instring, "(") To Len(instring) Step 1

           temp_string = Mid(instring, x, 1)

            If Mid(instring, x, 1) = "(" Then

                If marker = False Then
                z = x
                marker = True
                End If

            total = total + 1
            ElseIf Mid(instring, x, 1) = ")" Then
            total = total - 1


                If total = 0 Then
                marker = False
                b = b + 1
                paren_closure = x
                ReDim Preserve sent1(b)
                sent1(b) = Mid(instring, z, (x - z) + 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next

 Dim temp_sent1 As String
total = 0
marker = False



b = 0


Dim sent2()
ReDim sent2(UBound(sent1), 5)

 For n = 1 To UBound(sent1)
 temp_sent1 = sent1(n)
 temp_sent1 = Mid(temp_sent1, 2, Len(temp_sent1) - 2)
 b = 0
    For x = 1 To Len(temp_sent1)



           temp_string = Mid(instring, x, 1)

            If Mid(temp_sent1, x, 1) = "(" Then

                If marker = False Then
                z = x
                marker = True
                End If

            total = total + 1
            ElseIf Mid(temp_sent1, x, 1) = ")" Then
            total = total - 1


                If total = 0 Then
                marker = False
                b = b + 1
                paren_closure = x
                'ReDim Preserve sent2(n, b)

                sent2(n, b) = Mid(temp_sent1, z, (x - z) + 1)

                End If
            End If
        Next

        'this part of the code redimensions the side of the array

        ReDim Preserve b_arr(n)
        b_arr(n) = b


Next

b_max = MaxValOfIntArray(b_arr)
ReDim Preserve sent2(UBound(sent1), b_max)









End Function

Public Function MaxValOfIntArray(ByRef TheArray As Variant) As Integer
'This function gives max value of int array without sorting an array
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxIntegersIndex As Integer
MaxIntegersIndex = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(TheArray)
    If TheArray(i) > TheArray(MaxIntegersIndex) Then
        MaxIntegersIndex = i
    End If
Next
'index of max value is MaxValOfIntArray
MaxValOfIntArray = TheArray(MaxIntegersIndex)
End Function
</code>
```